# Is it a "Texas Accent" or a "Texan Accent"?

Tags: grammar

Is it proper to say "Texan accent" or "Texas accent" - or does it make any difference?

Comment: Ahm purdy shur Texans speak Texan in a Texan accent: what other way could they speak it? :)

Comment: Both are fine. You can use the adjective form or the noun as modifier form. What people -tend- to say is another matter. It's a "Southern" accent, not a "France" accent, and oppositely a "New York" accent, not a ... whatever-they-call-them-there accent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never heard anyone say *Texan accent*, while *Texas accent* is pretty common. [Ngrams agrees with me](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Texas%20accent,%20Texan%20accent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

On the other hand, you won't hear anyone say *England accent* or *America accent* over *English accent* or *American accent*. I am not sure about the reason behind this inconsistency but I suspect that perhaps with non-countries, the region/state/city name is used, regardless of the existence of an adjective form.

Comment: Um, no: [Ngrams doesn't agree with you](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Texas+accent%2CTexan+accent&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), because it certainly has heard people say that.  Yes, three times as many people say the other version, but that's far from negligible.

Comment: As a Brit, I'd be inclined to say *Texan*. I'd also say *Californian*. For the latter, [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=California+accent%2CCalifornian+accent&year_start=1950&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) still shows *Califoria* as higher, but with a less marked difference than for *Texas*

Comment: @TrevorD It's not just you: I'd say a *Californian* or *Texan* accent, too. Some states have easy adjectival forms, but many do not. Sure, if pressed into service you can variously have *Montanan, Floridian, New Mexican, Coloradan, Nevadan, Minnesotan, Virginian, Arizonan, Oregonian, Indianan, North Carolinan, South Dakotan* but you run into trouble with using that style for accents in places like *Connecticut, Massachusetts, Wyoming, Wisconsin, New York*.

Comment: Well, I would never say Texas accent and I would have wagered on it and have lost the sum. It might be more pertinent to know whether the Texans themselves refer to their dialect/accent as being *Texas* or *Texan*.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Don't the Texans call their dialect "normal", and name everyone else's accent?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens So do they call themselves "normal" or Texans? :) I'm sure Texans give a name to their speech, like Londoners recognize and say *cockney accents*, or *North London* ones.

Comment: As noted in @Gnawme's quote, Texans call their dialect "English".

Answer (score 5):

One speaks with a *Texas accent*, but one *talks Texan*. See [this article](http://articles.latimes.com/2013/jan/17/nation/la-na-texas-accent-20130118).

EDIT: By request, a relevant excerpt from the linked article. Note the distinction made between a "Texas accent" and "talking Texan."

> The Texas accent "has great symbolic value. It has a local identity
>   versus, say, Arizona English. That makes Texas English more
>   resilient," said Lars Hinrichs, an English language and linguistics
>   professor at UT Austin.
>
> There are many aspects to "talking Texan": pronunciation, cadence,
>   syntax, not to mention vocabulary. And, technically, there are several
>   Texas accents — the drawl of East Texans like Matthew McConaughey,
>   say, or the nasal West Texas twang of Laura Bush.

Comment: Interesting article, it would be a pity if, in the future, the link became broken or if you had to subscribe to the paper in order to read the piece. You should put the relevant info in block quotes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good suggestion, thanks. I edited the article accordingly.